# jaxb - xsd to java class for specified node

Tags: java, jaxb, xsd, xjc

I have an `XSD` file with many `ComplexType` defined in it. I'm using `XJC` to generate java classes from the `XSD` file. It will generate classes for all the `CompleXType` node defined in the schema file. Is there any way I can use a filter in `xjc` command so that I can get classes of the specified `ComplexType` only, Instead of generating classes for the whole `XSD` file?

Comment: Why don't you simply throw away what you don't want? Removing a handful of files can't be difficult.

Answer (score 2):

You can use binding files to *somewhat* achieve that:

- Use `<jaxb:schemaBindings map="false" ... />` to disable generation for the whole namespace/schema
- Use `<jaxb:class ref="com.acme.foo.Ignore"/>` to map "unwanted" classes to some (existing) `com.acme.foo.Ignore` class.